# General Idea Of Component System. Too much casting? Union like structs? other methods?

Tags: c#, data-structures, components, computer-science

I've been investigating the idea of a component based system. Imagine I have made them like so :

```cs
public class CObject
{
    public Component[] components;

    public T GetComponent<T>(string name = string.empty)
    {
        foreach(var c in components) if(c is T) if(name != string.empty || c.name == name) return c as T;
    }
}
```

and then we'll be able to get a component from a script like so :

```cs
// ... some code
DragonComponent dragonComponent = dragonObject.GetComponent<DragonComponent>();
// some code ...
```

but as you see it will require Boxing for each call...
I could make it more efficient by making an static dictionary for previous calls, and if a similar call was given, I could make it just use the dictionary. but still, it's very messy and not very efficient...

and there's the union-like structure I've heard where the `GetComponent` could be implemented like so :

```cs
public class CObject
{
    private class CTypes {
        public DragonComponent[] dragonComponents;
        public CameraFocus[] cameraFocuses;
    }

    CTypes components;

        public T GetComponent<T>()
        {
              switch(T)
              {
                   case DragonComponent:    return components.dragonComponents[0];
                   case CameraFocus:        return components.cameraFocuses[0];
              }
        }
}
```

which is super performant but very hard to implement... I have no idea how to automate the process of creating new types in the union-like structure.

What's the best approach?

thanks :D

Comment: Perhaps a `Dictionary<Type, List<object>>`? And then `public T GetComponent<T>() => _components[typeof(T)].OfType<T>()`

Comment: thanks. got the idea :D !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're trying to implement your own [IoC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) framework. There are lots of [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) frameworks out there. Even built into ASP.NET Core.

If that's  too overkill for you, there are many easier alternatives for your case though. First, you might think of a dictionary:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> _components = new();

public T GetComponent<T>() => (T)_components[typeof(T)];
```

Or, even more performant, use a static generic class:

```
private class ComponentCache<T>
{
   public static T Component { get; set; }
}

public T GetComponent<T>() => ComponentCache<T>.Component;
```

Also, [boxing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) applies only to **value** types. Either way though, believe me the performance hit is negligable for whatever little program you as a beginner are coding right now.

These are not complete examples, but I hope will give you some pointers.

Comment: Thank you! yes, performance is not that important, but it would still be nice for practice to keep that in mind too.